# Do we know how much of the ending of "A Memory of Light" did Robert Jordan write himself?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light, robert-jordan

In a comment to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/30518/1359) to a question speculating on an event in the epilogue of *A Memory of Light*, someone mentioned that:

> the ending was Robert Jordan's, written by him before he died.

Is there reference to back this up?  I know Robert Jordan passed on extensive notes to his wife and Brandon Sanderson, but I thought the details of those notes were a closely-held secret.  Was anything revealed, either before or after Jordan's passing, that indicated how much of the ending he had written?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I've seen they haven't said exactly who wrote what. The epilogue is mostly written by Robert Jordan, with a couple of scenes added by Brandon.

For example, it's [been said](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=874#33) in an interview the pipe scene was what Jordan was talking about when he said he had written the last scene.

> **KIRSTEN GESENBERG (23 JANUARY 2013)** Which scene is the "last scene"
>   that RJ said he wrote first? 
>   **BRANDON SANDERSON (23 JANUARY 2013)** Pipe
>   scene.

<sub>Source - Theoryland</sub>

Also on the same chat:

> **JAMES STARKE** Robert Jordan wrote the entire epilogue.
>
> **BRANDON SANDERSON** Almost all. There were a few small inserts by me.
>   Perrin was mine in the epilogue.
>
> **MIKE COX** I would like to know, how much of the last chapter was
>   written by RJ and how much did you do?
>
> **BRANDON SANDERSON** I did Perrin and some of the in-between writing with
>   Loial. RJ did Mat, Rand, scene exiting the mountain, and others.
>
> **BRANDON SANDERSON** There are places where I tweaked bits, per editing,
>   and places where I slipped in things he'd written to my sequences.
>
> **TEREZ** Was the last scene written or dictated?
>
> **BRANDON SANDERSON** Written down. As was the scene with Isam [in] the
>   prologue.
>
> **BRANDON SANDERSON** The Borderlander tower scene was dictated, I
>   believe.

There has been [some discussion](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=868#9) if the Cadsuane scene was added by Brandon (Peter Ahlstrom is Brandon's assistant):

> **ISABEL (9 JANUARY 2013)** One question: regarding the Cadsuane scene. It is said that this was added by you. Is that correct? Was
>   Cadsuane's fate in RJ's notes?
>
> **PETER AHLSTROM (9 JANUARY 2013)** Team Jordan said I could say that Brandon himself wrote the words of that little scene. Brandon is still
>   being closedmouthed about what specifically came from the notes, but
>   in general, Robert Jordan left quite a few notes on where people ended
>   up at the end of the book.
>
> **ISABEL** Am I right to assume that her implied fate wouldn't have been put in, if the notes say something different? (assuming there
>   were notes on it)
>
> **PETER AHLSTROM** The notes about fates at the end were not contradicted.

Answer (score 1):

He have several times written about this on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/WoT/comments/2hx31k/if_you_had_a_makeawish_and_for_some_reason_chose/ckx8wff).

Another: [What spoilers did you encounter before you finished the series? [spoilers]](http://www.reddit.com/r/WoT/comments/2s63uf/what_spoilers_did_you_encounter_before_you/cnnd3id)

> The epilogue.

I found this really funny (because the thread was obviously meant to ask about what spoilers readers encountered).

His [AMA](http://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/1ced7z/iamstilla_novelist_named_brandon_sanderson_ama/) proves u/mistborn is indeed Sanderson.